# Kubernetes Pod/container networking

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I have problem with networking to one single container in Pod.
I have created kubernetes cluster (one master and one node) for learning. Master is installed on one VM and Node is installed on second one VM.

**Node listing:**

```
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
kmaster   Ready    control-plane,master   68m   v1.20.2
ubuntu    Ready    <none>                 57m   v1.20.2
```

**Cluster info:**

```
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://192.168.0.102:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.0.102:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

Everything was working fine until VM's restarting.
One Pod with eclipse-mosquitto mqtt broker has some problem with networking with container inside.
```

**Below listing of pods:**

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
mqttbroker-574b696f76-x26jq   1/1     Running   0          57m   192.168.243.193   ubuntu   <none>           <none>
```

**Below description of problematic pod:**

```
Name:         mqttbroker-574b696f76-x26jq
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ubuntu/192.168.0.121
Start Time:   Mon, 08 Feb 2021 00:18:16 -0800
Labels:       app=mqttbroker
              pod-template-hash=574b696f76
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.243.193/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.243.193/32
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.243.193
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.243.193
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mqttbroker-574b696f76
Containers:
  mosquitto:
    Container ID:   docker://73417f8046abfd8773154cde02b7366f9d7c26331b03b141e89855deec71e273
    Image:          eclipse-mosquitto
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://eclipse-mosquitto@sha256:0916ce445d7f3945168966ab987515a081f2f2c761acb85ae00ff44d97d3a84f
    Port:           1883/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 08 Feb 2021 00:18:20 -0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     750m
      memory:  700Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        500m
      memory:     500Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-qgs7v (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-qgs7v:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-qgs7v
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

But when I inspect logs of container, I get some error with assigning IP:
**Container logs**

```
1612772300: mosquitto version 2.0.7 starting
1612772300: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1612772300: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1612772300: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1612772300: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1612772300: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1612772300: Error: Address not available
1612772300: mosquitto version 2.0.7 running
```

When I have checked addresses assigned to container, I saw strange IP mask.
I am supposing that this could be my problem. Below ifconfig output.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5A:27:37:13:F7:06  
          inet addr:192.168.243.193  Bcast:192.168.243.193  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Metric:1
          RX packets:14328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14315 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:927289 (905.5 KiB)  TX bytes:773046 (754.9 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:138 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:138 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7597 (7.4 KiB)  TX bytes:7597 (7.4 KiB)
```

Below **deployment** and services:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: mqttbroker
  labels:
    app: mqttbroker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mqttbroker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mqttbroker
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mosquitto
        image: eclipse-mosquitto
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "0.5"
            memory: "500Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "0.75"
            memory: "700Mi"
        ports:
          - name: mqttbroker-1883
            containerPort: 1883
```

**Cluster IP services**

```
apiVersion: v1  
kind: Service  
metadata:  
  name: mosquitto-service  
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:  
    app: mqttbroker  
  ports:
    - name: service-mqtt-1883
      protocol: TCP  
      port: 1883
      targetPort: 1883
```

**Nodeport IP services**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mosquittoservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "1883"
    port: 80
    targetPort:
    nodePort: 30081 # acces service via external port number
  selector:
    app: mqttbroker
```

**Listing of services:**

```
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE    SELECTOR
kubernetes          ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        116m   <none>
mosquitto-service   ClusterIP   10.98.70.62      <none>        1883/TCP       101m   app=mqttbroker
mosquittoservice    NodePort    10.106.207.192   <none>        80:30081/TCP   101m   app=mqttbroker
```

**Description of mosquitto-service**

```
Name:              mosquitto-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=mqttbroker
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.98.70.62
IPs:               10.98.70.62
Port:              service-mqtt-1883  1883/TCP
TargetPort:        1883/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.243.193:1883
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

**Description of mosquittoservice**

```
Name:                     mosquittoservice
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=mqttbroker
Type:                     NodePort
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.106.207.192
IPs:                      10.106.207.192
Port:                     1883  80/TCP
TargetPort:               1883/TCP
NodePort:                 1883  30081/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.243.193:1883
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

My question is what could cause this problem and how to fix it?

Thank you for answer!!

**Edit:**
When I am invoking container's function like below is working fine.

```
kubectl exec -it mqttbroker-574b696f76-x26jq -- mositto_sub -h localhost -p 1883 -t topic -C 4
```

If I change "localhost" to IP adress, I get connection refused.

```
kubectl exec -it mqttbroker-574b696f76-x26jq -- mositto_sub -h 192.168.0.102 -p 1883 -t topic -C 4
Error: Connection refused
command terminated with exit code 1
```

If I invoked function like below, I get also connection refused.

```
kubectl exec -it mqttbroker-574b696f76-x26jq -- mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.0.102 -p 30081 -t topic -C 4
Error: Connection refused
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: One should not use pictures for textual output (which is specifically mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Above and beyond the fact that one should not ask the reader to click on 8 links to view whatever content you have obfuscated therein. Also, any networking question belongs on https://ServerFault.com/

Comment: Please edit your question and post all information as text, not links. It will be easier to replicate your issue. Just to confirm, you are asking about issue with `Running` pod  -wxmft not about `CrashLoop` pod?

Comment: Sorry for confusing post, I thought that links could be better than long pasted text outputs. Anyway, I will edit my post.
@PjoterS My question was about pod -wxmft.

Comment: It's your local env or cloud env? Did you allow traffic on port 30081? I guess your issue is related with mqtt configuration. There is similar thread on Github: [Mosquitto unable to start ](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2074) where solution is to add `listener 1883` to your config file. Second thing is `Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.` which its pointing that it should work only on localhost? I guess [this comment](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2074#issuecomment-773910523) answer your question

Comment: @PjoterS I am running cluster locally, as two vm machines. I haven't provided any special traffic configuration for 30081 port. Should something configuration be done for port 30081?

Your suggestion could be accurately regarding conf file. I have to learn how to mount conf file as exteral volume and I will try to run mosquitto with listner 1883. There is another interesting parameter: bind_interace. I will try and give feedback.

Comment: @MarcinO any updates?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for late response. When I mount mosquitto.conf file as ConfigMap, where I specified "listener 1883" my broker is working correctly and other subscribers get data. Thank you for help @PjoterS

Answer (score 0):

Issue and solution was determined in comment section.

Root cause of the issue was lack of configuration for `listener` on `1883`.

Other possible solutions for similar issues can be found in Github Thread - [Mosquitto unable to start](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2074).

Issue was resolved by using [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) where `listener` on `1883` was specified.

> When I mount mosquitto.conf file as ConfigMap, where I specified "listener 1883" my broker is working correctly and other subscribers get data.